# How do I pause the command window when launching an app?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-emulator

When I launch an Android app via Ctrl+F11 on Eclipse, there are two black command windows (DOS-like) that appear briefly with some important messages in them. Obviously, I can't read what's in them in that brief moment.

Is there a way to pause/freeze them?

Update: @Mayra's answers below provided great tips but they did not solve the problem of pausing/freezing these windows. I know for sure that they contain information **not** in the Console and not in the logcat. So the question remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless an answer that describes step-by-step **how** to pause the command window when launching an android app from Eclipse (to the emulator) comes along, the accepted answer is: This cannot be done.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what windows you are referring to, but you shouldn't have to do anything like that.

All relevant information is displayed in either the Console or logcat tabs.  You can open either via window -> show view.

You can also access logcat by running `adb logcat` from the command line.

Comment: are you sure that everything that appears on those "DOS" windows also appears on the Console or the logcat tabs?

Comment: As I said,I don't know what windows you are referring to, but I do know that I have never heard anyone refer to them or need anything beyond the two I mentioned.  Use the window -> show view menu to open logcat, or use the DDMS perspective.

Comment: thanks. The reason I need to see what's in these 2 windows is because I need to troubleshoot why an APK won't install in a 64-bit environment. I gave you +1 twice but I can't accept this answer as it doesn't explain how to freeze those windows. There must be a way.

Comment: Did you try installing from the commandline?  adb install myproject.apk

Comment: No. Thanks for this tip (as you can tell, I am a total newbie in Android development). I would like, though, to make my 64-bit android development environment work exactly as my 32-bit android development works. That is, everything working smoothly and automatically via Eclipse.